# SQLite - pre allocating database size

Tags: c++, sqlite, embedded

Is there a way to pre allocate my SQLite database to a certain size?  Currently I'm adding and deleting a number of records and would like to avoid this over head at create time.

Comment: Why do you assume that there is an overhead that you can avoid. Does it even matter for your application if you could? I think you are tying to do "premature optimization" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_(computer_science) and from Donald Knuth we learned that "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: There is a legitimate need to do this that is not tied to efficiency.  [Certain file systems](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mikelag/archive/2011/02/09/how-fragmentation-on-incorrectly-formatted-ntfs-volumes-affects-exchange.aspx) have a limit on how many fragments the file can have.  If you know how big your database will be, you can avoid the problem by pre-allocating the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a hack - Insert a bunch of data into the database till the database size is what you want and then delete the data. This works because:

> "When an object (table, index, or
>   trigger) is dropped from the database,
>   it leaves behind empty space. This
>   empty space will be reused the next
>   time new information is added to the
>   database. But in the meantime, the
>   database file might be larger than
>   strictly necessary."

Naturally, this isn't the most reliable method. (Also, you will need to make sure that auto_vacuum is disabled for this to work). You can learn more here - http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html

Comment: As I said in my question, this is what I currently doing.  But thanks for the auto_vacuum hint!

Comment: Glad to help. Another thing that would help you slightly improve the performance of the SQLite db is to make sure that you defragment the db file (especially if you are using windows).

Answer (score 9):

The fastest way to do this is with the zero_blob function:

**Example:**

Y:> **sqlite3 large.sqlite**
SQLite version 3.7.4
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> **create table large (a)**;
sqlite> **insert into large values (zeroblob(1024*1024));**
sqlite> **drop table large;**
sqlite> **.q**

Y:> **dir large.sqlite**
 Volume in drive Y is Personal
 Volume Serial Number is 365D-6110

Directory of Y:\

01/27/2011  12:10 PM         1,054,720 large.sqlite

---

**Note:** As Kyle properly indicates in his comment:

There is a limit to how big each blob can be, so you may need to insert multiple blobs if you expect your database to be larger than ~1GB.

Comment: Note that there is a [limit](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) to how big each blob can be, so you may need to insert multiple blobs if you expect your database to be larger than ~1GB.

Comment: @Kyle: Good point, I've updated the answer to include that information