# Is there a way to reserve a specific amount of disk space for a Sqlite database at creation time?

Tags: sqlite

I'm considering using Sqlite for a project but haven't been able to find a non-hacky way of forcing the database to grow to a specific size when I first create it.  Is it possible?

The problem I'm trying to solve is that my database needs to be able to grow up to a fixed size (let's call it 200 MB) without experiencing any "disk full" scenarios.  Therefore, when my app first starts, I'd like to reserve 200 MB for the database.  If there's not all 200 MB available, I can fail the whole thing and have the user free up space before trying again.  But once created and running I know that I'll never run into a "disk full" issue as long as my data size stays below 200 MB.

As far as I can tell, the way to accomplish this would be to create a 200 MB blob and store it in the database and then immediately delete it....which would grow the database on disk and then reuse all those pages for the actual database data.  I'm wondering if there's a better way though?

Thanks!

Comment: It would seem you already have [the ubiquitous way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827010/sqlite-pre-allocating-database-size)

Comment: I guess you *could* make a single 210MB file with `dd`, create a filesystem on it and mount it as loopback, then you'd have a directory with around 200MB of space in it.

Comment: Thanks Stu; in all my searches that particular response never came up.  I appreciate it and marked this question a duplicate of that one.